# Python canvas save drawing problem with postscript sizes

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png, tkinter-canvas

So i have the problem that i need to save out the drawing to a .png file with the same size of the canvas, but after converting the canvas into postscript with (width, height) params it gives back a 751x752 sized .png file. I read somewhere that the postscript automatically strips the canvas.
I need the original size.
Thanks for helping!

Here's a piece from the code:
With the draw function you can draw something in to the canvas and the goal is to save the drawing.

```
               def draw(event):
                x, y = event.x, event.y
                r = 20
                canvas.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r, fill='black')


            canvas = CTkCanvas(self.game_started_window, width=1000, height=1000, bg='white')
            canvas.place(x=900, y=0)
            canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', draw)

            def save_png():
                    postscript = canvas.postscript(colormode = 'color', width = 1000 ,height =1000)
                    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(postscript.encode('utf-8')))
                    img.save(f'samples/comp.png', format = 'png')
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer as it is incomplete and lacks context.